# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The underlying connection was closed

Tags: umbraco, azure-blob-storage

Has anybody else experienced this? It looks like the code was not able to connect to the Azure container. I checked the health of the container and there has been no issues reported for the past 24 hours. Where else is a good place to look at?

```
2018-07-16 01:41:13,906 [P13036/D2/T1] ERROR Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase - An unhandled exception occurred
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: The read operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
   at System.Net.SSPISecureChannelType.DecryptMessage(SafeDeleteContext context, SecurityBufferDescriptor inputOutput, UInt32 sequenceNumber)
   at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.EncryptDecryptHelper(OP op, SSPIInterface SecModule, SafeDeleteContext context, SecurityBuffer[] input, UInt32 sequenceNumber)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.Decrypt(Byte[] payload, Int32& offset, Int32& count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 695
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 604
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.Create(BlobContainerPublicAccessType accessType, BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlobContainer.cs:line 68
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType accessType, BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlobContainer.cs:line 233
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlobContainer.cs:line 196
   at Our.Umbraco.FileSystemProviders.Azure.AzureFileSystem.CreateContainer(CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient, String containerName, BlobContainerPublicAccessType accessType)
   at Our.Umbraco.FileSystemProviders.Azure.AzureFileSystem..ctor(String containerName, String rootUrl, String connectionString, Int32 maxDays, Boolean useDefaultRoute, BlobContainerPublicAccessType accessType)
   at Our.Umbraco.FileSystemProviders.Azure.AzureFileSystem.GetInstance(String containerName, String rootUrl, String connectionString, String maxDays, String useDefaultRoute, String usePrivateContainer)
   at Our.Umbraco.FileSystemProviders.Azure.AzureBlobFileSystem..ctor(String containerName, String rootUrl, String connectionString, String maxDays, String useDefaultRoute)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Umbraco.Core.IO.FileSystemProviderManager.GetUnderlyingFileSystemNoCache(String alias, Func`1 fallback)
   at Umbraco.Core.IO.FileSystemProviderManager.<>c__DisplayClass56_0`1.<GetFileSystemProvider>b__0(String _)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Umbraco.Core.IO.FileSystemProviderManager.GetFileSystemProvider[TFileSystem](Func`1 fallback)
   at Umbraco.Core.IO.FileSystemProviderManager.CreateWellKnownFileSystems()
   at Umbraco.Core.IO.FileSystemProviderManager..ctor()
   at Umbraco.Core.IO.FileSystemProviderManager.get_Current()
   at Umbraco.Core.Services.MediaService..ctor(IDatabaseUnitOfWorkProvider provider, RepositoryFactory repositoryFactory, ILogger logger, IEventMessagesFactory eventMessagesFactory, IDataTypeService dataTypeService, IUserService userService)
   at Umbraco.Core.Services.ServiceContext.<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<BuildServiceCache>b__12()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Umbraco.Web.Models.Mapping.MediaModelMapper.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<ConfigureMappings>b__9(IMemberConfigurationExpression`1 expression)
   at AutoMapper.MappingExpression`2.ForDestinationMember(IMemberAccessor destinationProperty, Action`1 memberOptions) in c:\dev\AutoMapper\src\AutoMapper\Internal\MappingExpression.cs:line 542
   at AutoMapper.MappingExpression`2.ForMember(Expression`1 destinationMember, Action`1 memberOptions) in c:\dev\AutoMapper\src\AutoMapper\Internal\MappingExpression.cs:line 183
   at Umbraco.Web.Models.Mapping.MediaModelMapper.ConfigureMappings(IConfiguration config, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
   at Umbraco.Core.CoreBootManager.<InitializeModelMappers>b__32_0(IConfiguration configuration)
   at AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(Action`1 action) in c:\dev\AutoMapper\src\AutoMapper\Mapper.cs:line 237
   at Umbraco.Core.CoreBootManager.InitializeModelMappers()
   at Umbraco.Core.CoreBootManager.Initialize()
   at Umbraco.Web.WebBootManager.Initialize()
   at Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase.StartApplication(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: Same thing just happened to me. Not using Umbraco, but this started happening yesterday on Azure without any code changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where any HttpClient calls (in C#) starting failing in Azure with this above error.
This started happening without me changing anything on Azure, or to the WebApp.

Changing the application from 32bit to 64bit fixed the issue.

- Go to Azure portal
- Choose on your app service
- Go to 'Application Settings' under settings
- Change the platform from 32bit to 64bit
- This will probably automatically restart the web service, but I did this manually as well

I am waiting on Azure for an official response on what changed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience David.

Comment: @david-smit Do you get answer from Azure support? I have same issue

Comment: @AleksandrVishnyakov not yet. I am still in discussion with them. Will post my outcome here in a few days

Comment: Got feedback from Azure: they couldn't pinpoint it to a specific issue, because the only way to replicate this is to change it back to 32bit, which may break the site and this is unfortunately not an option for me.